# Forefront Identity Manager 2010 no users

Tags: microsoft-forefront-2010

I've been scratching my head for a day or so trying to learn FIM.

I attempted to walk through this [tutorial](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/648.how-do-i-synchronize-users-from-active-directory-domain-services-to-fim.aspx) which is one of the things I want to use it for - but I couldn't get it to work (users don't show up in FIM).

I am following this other [tutorial](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee534911(WS.10).aspx) which uses a simple CSV to popular users in FIM - which I also can't get to work.

I think part of my problem is that I don't seem to have any users in FIM (this is from a fresh install): https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6EC5.png

I have read from many sources that you should at least have administrator in there.

Also I get export errors from the CSV tutorial that say "The endpoint could not dispatch the request."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem - by default no users will show up in that page. You have to actually search if you want to see users.

Searching for % will display all users in FIM.